# TLS and SSL for Java apache commons email

Tags: java, email, apache-commons

Can we use SSL and TLS both at the same time while sending an e-mail using apache commons email library?

Comment: Just so we are clear here: What in your eyes is the difference between SSL and TLS?

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't

Comment: I'm setting TLS=true & SSL=true inside the configuration and it still works. I know that this is incorrect. But not sure why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.
Please note that TLS is a replacement of SSL. In order to use a secure connection client and server agree on certain SSL/TLS version, exchange keys and then send data with the version of protocol and keys agreed. You can't use 2 different versions of encryption at the same time because using of one is more than enough because it is PCI compliant.

Comment: I'm setting TLS=true & SSL=true inside the configuration and it still works. I know that this is incorrect. But not sure why it works.

Comment: You set the possible protocols for connection to be established, when the client connects to server it will agree with server on protocol and use only one certain protocol and version( i.e. TLS 1.2) , though client and server can be compatible with both SSL and TLS.